# How to include newline in email message using send_mail and django?

Tags: django, email, newline

I would like to send email message with newlines. Let say, by following code:

```
send_mail("subject", "Hi  George\n Thanks for registration", "from", "to")
```

I expect:

Hi George

Thanks for registration

Whereas that what I get is:
Hi George\n Thanks for registration

Email is send to a gmail account if that matters.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `\n` works for me. Try `u"Hi ...`

Comment: Edit: actually \n worked now... I have certainly made a mistake before  posting that

Comment: danihp - exactly it works, thanks for help

Comment: If you mail content is longer, compose it as string and use it in the send mail function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way you can accomplish that is by puting the mail text in template and use django template loader to render it with context.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
context = {}  # Fill it with your context
send_mail(
    'Subject',
    render_to_string('core/emails/email.txt', context),
    'sender@mail.com',
    ['receiver@mail.com'],
    fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: If you're using the console email backend, would it still show the "\n" characters, even though in the actual email the user would not see them? @Vladislav

Answer (score 1):

yes 
"%0A" for a new line
it works well.

Answer (score 0):

try using:
`%0A`  for a new line
`%26` for &
`%3f` for ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is working for me using "f" string see example bellow.

```
f'New contact from : {message_name} \n Email: {message_email}  \n 
            Subject: {message_subject}  \n Message:{message_content}'
```